# Regression analysis with likert items

Tags: regression, likert

I am trying to analyse the relationship between some independent variables and a dependent variable where the independent variables are on a scale 1 (too weak) to 10 (too strong) with 5 being an ideal and the dependent variable are on a scale 1 to 10 where 10 is the ideal.

Could you suggest what technique to use to analyse these?

Comment: Check out the likert tag questions for some suggestions.

Comment: In addition to the [tag:likert] tag, you might want to explore threads categorized under the [tag:ordinal] tag or w/ both [ordinal & logistic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordinal+logistic) tags. Since your response variable is only 1 likert item (ie not a scale composed of many) you really probably should treat it as ordinal. As for the independent variables, they don't matter as much.

Comment: See my blog post [how to analyze Likert type dependent variables](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-analyze-likert-type-dependent-variables/)

Comment: Would that be matter if the ideal score of the dependent variable is 5 instead of 10?